# Why is specific heat capacity at constant pressure not equal to the rate of change of internal energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, ideal-gas

The formula for internal energy is $U= nC(v)dT$.
But why cant we use U=nC(p)dt where C(p) is the specific heat at constant pressure

Someone might say that we can use $C(v)$ because Internal energy of an ideal gas does not depend on the volume so even if volume is changing we can use $C(v)$.  *But then the internal energy of an ideal gas is also not dependent on the pressure.  Its only depended on the temperature of the gas. So why cant we use $C(p)$?*

Also for real gasses both $C(v)$, $C(p)$ shall be correct.  Isn't it?

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201795/specific-heat-capacity-at-constant-volume-vs-constant-pressure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Thermodynamics, the specific heat capacity at constant volume and the specific heat capacity at constant pressure are physical properties of a material (*irrespective of process*) that are **precisely defined** as follows:
$$C_v=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V$$
and $$C_p=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P$$where the specific internal energy U (per mole or per unit mass) and the specific enthalpy H (per mole or per unit mass) are also physical properties of the material (*irrespective of process*), with $$H=U+PV$$where V is the specific volume (per mole or per unit mass).  For an ideal gas, U and H are functions only of temperature, and not pressure or volume.  Therefore, for an ideal gas $$C_p=\left(\frac{dH}{dT}\right)=\frac{dU}{dT}+\frac{d(PV)}{dT}=C_v+\frac{d(RT)}{dT}=C_v+R$$

**ADDENDUM**

*Problem 1*:  This is a 2 step process involving 1 mole of ideal gas.  In Step 1, the system starts out at $P_1$, $V_1$, and $T_1$, and is heated at constant volume to temperature $T_2$ (and corresponding pressure $P_2$).  In Step 2, the gas is allowed to expand isothermally and reversibly (being held in contact with a constant temperature bath at $T_2)$ until the pressure is again $P_1$.

*Step 1 Questions*:

In terms of $T_1$, $T_2$, and $P_1$, what is the final pressure $P_2$ at the end of Step 1?

In terms of $T_1$ and $T_2$, what is $\Delta (PV)$ in Step 1?

In terms of $T_1$ and $T_2$, what is $\Delta U$, $\Delta H$, W, and Q in Step 1?

*Step 2 Questions*:

In terms of $T_1$, $T_2$, and $V_1$, what is the final volume at the end of Step 2?

What is $\Delta (PV)$ in Step 2?

In terms of $T_1$ and $T_2$, what is W and Q in Step 2?

What is $\Delta U$ and $\Delta H$ in Step 2?

*Overall Process Questions*:

In terms of $T_1$ and $T_2$, what are Q and W for the overall process?

In terms of $T_1$ and $T_2$, what are $\Delta U$ and $\Delta H$ for the overall process?

What is $\Delta U$ divided by $\Delta T = (T_2-T_1)$ for the overall process?

What is $\Delta H$ divided by $\Delta T = (T_2-T_1)$ for the overall process?

Comment: But in an adaibatic process we take U= C(v)dT  where Q=0 and W is not equal to zero. Volume is changing and dV is not 0. Also P is changing. Why don't we use C(p)dT here.

Comment: Because the first law of thermodynamics calls for the use of U, not H.  Of course, if the process is also reversible, one could also use either $dU=C_vdT=-PdV$ or $dH=C_pdT=VdP$.  The two equations are equivalent.  You are aware that, for an ideal gas, U and H are functions only of T (and not P or V), so dU is always equal to CvdT and dH is always equal to CpdT (irrespective of what P and V are doing), correct?

Comment: But when we work at constant volume only then U= Q

Comment: But when we work at constant volume only then U= Q but C(V) is defined as the heat capacity at constant V. When the volume is not constant then its not heat capacity at constant V. Like in JohnRennie's answer he tells why when W=0 then Q=U and only then U=C(v)dT . How can we before hand take U=C(V)dT . It could be anything . It can be C(P) or any value of C.  You said that U for ideal gas is independent of V And P. Then if dU/dV = dU/dP =0 Hence C(v) and C(P) both are OK. I am getting confused. Even while calculating Joule Coefficient we use C(V). If the gas was real then also C(V)  is right ?

Comment: Let's forget about Cp for the moment.  Suppose we hold the volume of an ideal gas constant, and we increase the temperature.  Then the change in internal energy is $\Delta U=C_v\Delta T$, right.  Then we change the volume to any other value, holding the temperature constant.  This can be done by holding the gas in contact with a constant temperature reservoir.  For this second step, $Q=W=\int{PdV}$, and $\Delta U=0$  So the overall change in U is still $\Delta U=C_v\Delta T$ Now, since U depends only on T, it doesn't depend on what path we took for get from the initial state to the 2nd state.

Comment: If your confusion continues, I can help.  I will add 4 focusing problems to my post, for you to solve.  Each of these 4 processes has two steps, one of which is either at constant volume or at constant pressure.  I will ask you to determine the changes in U and H, the work W, and the heat transferred Q for each of these process steps and for the overall process.  After you get done, you will have a good understanding of how this all works.

Comment: Your 2nd last comment made everything crystal clear. I understand it perfectly now. But  just one thing this wouldn't have been the case if the gas had been real ? And yes please add the problems to your post. Though I have understood I want to try to see whether my concepts are perfectly clear or not. It will be a nice learning. I will answer 12 hours later. Its night here. Thank You

Comment: For a real gas, U is a function of both T and V (or, equivalently, T and P).

Comment: Sorry for answering late. My exams were going on (finals ) and I therefore didn't get time to answer . The answers in order are - P1T2/T1. The second one should be 0(by P1V1=nRT1 and P2V1=nRT1 and then substituting value of P2 and subtracting) but by differentials I also felt it should V*delta(P). delta (U)=C(v)(T2 - T1) ,delta(H)=C(p)(T2-T1) . Q= delta (U).  For 2nd process V2=T2V1/T1  , delta(PV) =nR(T2-T1). W should be nr(T2-T1) but by P2V2-P1V1 I got 0 by putting the vlues of P2 and V2 of the respective processes. delta(U)=Cv(T2-T1) , delta(H)=Cp(T2-T1).

Comment: I was getting confused in the questions of the overall process. I feel the other answers should be right except the delta (PV) ones. Since i just gave Physics exam a week it would very good if i can build on these concepts. Please help .Thanks

Comment: And just one thing extra. in the 1st law Q=U+W. Is the w only the external work done by the gas on the say piston or is it also the internal work done by the gas on its molecules on expansion because there are internal forces in a real gas.

Comment: The former.  It's the work done by the gas at its external boundary on its surroundings.

Comment: But we calculate the internal work in joule expansion of real gas to calculate the joule coefficient. we use the internal pressure a/(V^2) to calculate that work.

Comment: Are you talking about joule-thompson through a valve or porous plug, or are you talking about Joule's experiment where there is a paddle rotating in a fluid, driven by an external weight which falls?

Comment: Or are you talking about the experiment in which you have a rigid chamber with a barrier, and on one side of the barrier you have gas under pressure, and, on the other side of the barrier you have vacuum.  And you remove the barrier, and let the system re-equiibrate?

Comment: I am talking about the joule thompson expansion through a porous plug. In my book the author calculates the the joule coefficient by taking the internal work done = decrease in kinetic energy of the gas particles. Internal work is a/(V^2)dV , a/(V^2) is the internal pressure by the van der waal's equation. I answer of of the coefficient is then taken out by seeing that work done = increase in potential energy = decrease in kinetic energy  & d(K.E)=C(v)dT. Therefore answer he gives is C(v)dT= -a/(V^2)dV .

Comment: BY this then the W in the first law shall be the internal work also at least for the real gasses because then even that can cause change in internal energy .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56173/discussion-between-chester-miller-and-e2n).

Comment: Yes please . Can a post apicture of what the author has written in the chat .

Answer (score 2):

The internal energy of a closed system is defined by:

$$ dU = \delta Q + \delta W $$

i.e. it is the energy added to the system plus the work done on the system. The work is $-PdV$ giving:

$$ dU = \delta Q - PdV $$

If we work at constant volume then $dV = 0$ and the internal energy is then simply the heat added i.e. $C_vdT$. If we work at constant pressure then the heat added is $C_pdT$, but we'd have to calculate the work done by the system as it expanded and then subtract that off to get the internal energy.

Comment: Oh! Thanks . I just did not think about that. Just one thing more . Could you please tell me ( sort examples ) that which relations developed in the thermodynamics that an undergrad studies change due to the faulty assumption of an ideal gas. Obviously 1st & 2nd laws won't change ( since they are laws , but I can't prove it) and I know about van der waals equation. But which general results ( like above) would change due to the gas being real shall change because I feel that certain equations shall change ( I can not express it properly)..... ! Thank you !

Comment: But in an adaibatic process we take U= C(v)dT  where Q=0 and W is not equal to zero. Volume is changing and dV is not 0. Also P is changing. Why don't we use C(p)dT here.